# Pyephem - Variables not assigning properly?

Tags: pyephem

I'm trying to set up pyephem to take a right ascension and declination, then use that to calculate a body's altitude and azimuth. However, I'm having issues assigning these traits. Here's what I do:

```
obj = ephem.FixedBody()
print (x) #x was assigned to 5.575
obj._ra = x
print (obj._ra)
```

The output of this is:

```
5.575
21:17:41.75
```

As I understand it, I should be inputting the RA value in Hours, and the Dec value in degrees. That's how I'm doing it. But for some reason, I assign 5.575 to the variable obj._ra, and that variable doesn't HOLD the proper value. I'm getting the same issue with my declination values. Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. What you have to do is declare your angles in "XX:YY:ZZ" format with hours minutes and seconds. You can't just declare as a float, because then it assumes you're talking about radians. 5.575 radians got converted to 21:17:41.75, because it assumed that I was feeding it radians instead of hours.

Comment: Yes! This is an annoying inconsistency in the Python-to-C layer of PyEphem, but I am not sure how to fix it without breaking existing programs that correct for the awkwardness. This is part of why I created Skyfield to eventually replace PyEphem: so that all units have to be specified on the way into and out of the library!